# Key value pair string generation out of an array React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have following array (foodDetailsList)

```
  [{"food_id": 5, "quantity": 100, "quantity_unit": gm}, 
  {"food_id": 45, "quantity": 200, "quantity_unit": gm}, 
  {"food_id": 22, "quantity": 300, "quantity_unit": gm}]
```

Out of which, I wish to create following variable String as an OUTPUT:

```
'food[0][food_id]': '5',
'food[0][quantity]': '100',
'food[0][quantity_unit]': 'gm',
'food[1][food_id]': '45',
'food[1][quantity]': '200',
'food[1][quantity_unit]': 'gm',
'food[2][food_id]': '45',
'food[2][quantity]': '200',
'food[2][quantity_unit]': 'gm'
```

I wanted to try something like following:

```
const createString = ()=>{
    let finalFoodList =[];
    foodDetailsList.map((food,key) =>{
              finalFoodList.push({
            'food['+[key]+'][food_id]'`:food.id,
            'food['+[key]+'][quantity]'`:food.quantity
              });
            });
    console.log("final variable is : ",finalFoodList.toString);
}
```

Need to improve above code syntatically so that above output is received.

Comment: Is your wanted output an object?

Comment: I wish the output as a String exactly as mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your `arr` of objects. For each object you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it to obtain the `food_id`, `quantity` and `quantity_unit` properties. Based on that, you can return a string in the format which you desired, using the index `i` provided in the `.map()` callback as the index for `food` in your string. Once you have obtained an array of strings, you can join each string using [`.join('\n')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{"food_id": 5, "quantity": 100, "quantity_unit": 'gm'}, 
  {"food_id": 45, "quantity": 200, "quantity_unit": 'gm'}, 
  {"food_id": 22, "quantity": 300, "quantity_unit": 'gm'}];
  
  
const res = arr.map(({food_id, quantity, quantity_unit}, i) => 
  `'food[${i}][food_id]': '${food_id}'\n'food[${i}][quantity]': '${quantity}'\n'food[${i}][quantity_unit]': '${quantity_unit}'`
).join('\n');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function to iterate over your original array, then use `Object.keys` to get all keys of the contained food-objects and map over those keys as well to get a generic solution like this:

```js
const foodList = [
  {"food_id": 5, "quantity": 100, "quantity_unit": 'gm'}, 
  {"food_id": 45, "quantity": 200, "quantity_unit": 'gm'}, 
  {"food_id": 22, "quantity": 300, "quantity_unit": 'gm'}]


const foodString = foodList.map((food, index) => 
   Object.keys(food).map(key => `'food[${index}][${key}]': '${food[key]}'`).join('\n')
 ).join('\n');

console.log(foodString);
```

The `join()`-Method joins all array-members as string with linebreaks as separators.

Comment: and how to create a hashmap of it instead of string?

Comment: Do you mean a Map-Object? Or what exactly is a Hash-Map for you in JavaScript? I am asking cause it is not a native type in JS.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const foodList = [
    {"food_id": 5, "quantity": 100, "quantity_unit": gm}, 
    {"food_id": 45, "quantity": 200, "quantity_unit": gm}, 
    {"food_id": 22, "quantity": 300, "quantity_unit": gm}
];

const createString = () => {
    const foodLen = foodList.length;
    let finalFoodList = foodList.map((food, index) => {
        return index !== foodLen ? (
            `'food[${index}][food_id]': '${food.food_id}',\n
            'food[${index}][quantity]': '${food.quanatity}',\n
            'food[${index}][quantity_unit]': '${food.quantity_unit}',\n`
        ) : (
             `'food[${index}][food_id]': '${food.food_id}',\n
            'food[${index}][quantity]': '${foof.quanatity}',\n
            'food[${index}][quantity_unit]': '${food.quantity_unit}'
        );
    });
}
```

1. get length of foodList array.
2. map function creates new array.
3. second parameter in map function gives current iteration number.
4. we use ternary operator to return conditional output.